# The action 'edit1' could not be found for SubjectsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

First post here... doing the ROR tutorial and found similar questions regarding this issue... but of course none worked. Anyway following the tutorial everything works except when clicking on this link I get the error `The action 'edit1' could not be found for SubjectsController`... any help is greatly appreciated!Myself and the tutorial are both using same version too... 4.0.

SubjectsController:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.sorted
  end

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new({:name => "Default"})
  end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    # Save the object
    if @subject.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # Find an existing object using form parameters
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    # Update the object
    if @subject.update_attributes(subject_params)
      # If update succeeds, redirect to the index action
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @subject.id)
    else
      # If update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    subject = Subject.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end


  private

    def subject_params
      # same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # - raises an error if :subject is not present
      # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end

end
```

Edit.html

```
    <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subjects edit">
  <h2>Update Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Subject form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Update Subject") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

routes file

```
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do


  root "demo#index"

  #get "demo/index"
  match ':controller(/:action(:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Other than this I'm on Chrome and windows 7.

```
Code for Show link:

    <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subjects show">
  <h2>Show Subject</h2>

  <table summary="Subject detail view">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td><%= @subject.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <td><%= @subject.position %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Visible?</th>
      <td><%= @subject.visible ? 'true' : 'false' %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Created</th>
      <td><%= @subject.created_at %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Updated</th>
      <td><%= @subject.updated_at %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>



Code for delete link:

        <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subjects delete">
  <h2>Delete Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>

    <p class="reference-name"><%= @subject.name %></p>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Delete Subject") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: On clicking which link you get that error?

Comment: @suslov... when I replace that I get a routing error.... "No route matches [GET] "/subjects/edit1""

Comment: @pavan... all three links give me the same error... except the "edit" would be replaced with "show" or "delete".. but the "add new subject" link works.

Comment: Please post the code to that relevant links.

Comment: @Pavan... I posted the code to the other 2 links... let me know if anything else is needed... and I really no just about nothing so feel free to talk to me like a 2nd... no.... 1st grader... using ror to start learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller contains edit action, but not edit1. edit1 is a result of action being concatenated with parameter due to invalid route setup.
In your routes config a slash `/` is missing

It should be like this

```
 match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
                             ^
                             |
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slash to the 'match' route as Mladen suggests will fix your immediate problem. However, having that default route is no longer recommended; it's better to be explicit about your routes.

This will give you the 'standard' REST-ful routes, to replace the 'match' route in your routes file:

```
resources :subjects
```

If you're really using a 'GET delete' action in your controller you would need a 'member' entry to add that, but usually there's just a link on the show and/or edit form that goes right to the 'destroy' action to delete a record; not sure why you would need a separate 'delete' view.